# alternative to pass values via php POST

Tags: php, post, get

I'm currently developing a cakePHP app and came up with the problem of saving a form with LOTS of inputs.

I have column A and column B in which there are items with several atributes (name, desc, color, etc), when i move items from either column to the other and clic save (using POST to pass values) it crashes or malfunctions not saving.

This is due php's max_input_vars which limits the amount to 1000. My first thought was to limit the amount if inputs for each item but it'd still exist a limit.

The question is, what's the good practice to handle large forms such as this saving values to database for almost limitless items/inputs??

Comment: use some client-side code to convert those field/value pairs into something serialized, e.g. json text, then you pass back a SINGLE `data=long_json_text_here` value pair.

Comment: At this point, you are probably dealing with a somewhat complex app.  If you have 1000's of fields do you really want to rely on a single POST, or should you consider AJAX methodlogies to incrementally POST and save field data?  Similarly you could POST a JSON representation of your data from the form via AJAX and just decode the structure from raw input.

Comment: I have put values in a JSON format and sent it through post as one variable..... `$_POST['myvar'] == '{ "color" : "grey", "lunch" : "taco" }'` and then used `json_decode()` but I used js/jquery to achieve that on submit.

Comment: Been thinking on doing that It's just i have never used it. I'll post the results soon, this may be the way. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. I just used SESSIONS to deal with the problem, now it works perfectly, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this from your php.ini

```
[suhosin]

suhosin.post.max_vars = 20000

suhosin.request.max_vars = 20000
```

Comment: Thanks man, but the thing is I don't want to modify that since in a normal enviroment you don't have access to hired hosting's php.ini, besides it has to exist a pretty way to achieve it.